# CSRF token cookie vulnerabilities during security scan

Tags: python, django, security, cookies

I am making a simple website for my employer using Django, and I had to run the code through a security scan to test for vulnerabilities. One of the issues is cookie vulnerabilities that I can find documentation to find for.

The cookie vulnerabilities are raised when logging in to my website.

Here is the error - the scan is run by OCIO-Internet-Scan

> CVSS: 5.0 Message: csrftoken Cookie has problem(s) `csrftoken =`
>   `J4S6ZO7ssz4TUIlRNv9d95mCFomAbXO1; Host = [removed] Path = /`
>
> 1. Cookie can be cached.
> 2. Cookie is persistent. Cookie expires at : Wed, 07 Jun 2017
>
> Persistent session-handling cookies: When a session-handling cookie is
>   set persistently, it allows the cookie to be valid even after a user
>   terminates a session. Therefore an attacker can use a session cookie
>   stored as a text file by the browser to access restricted information.
>   Cacheable cookies: A cachable cookie could be cached at a proxy or a
>   gateway. It can result in serving a cookie value that is out of date
>   or stale. An attacker may also steal such cookies if he has
>   compromised that proxy or gateway.

My question is, where exactly can I make changes to the csrftoken behavior for this? I can't find it using google, and I cannot bring the website up until this is fixed. Am I even able to change how csrf acts to accommodate these errors?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want to change the [`CSRF_COOKIE_AGE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-age) setting to `None`:

> Default: **31449600** (approximately 1 year, in seconds)
>
> The age of CSRF cookies, in seconds.
>
> The reason for setting a long-lived expiration time is to avoid
>   problems in the case of a user closing a browser or bookmarking a page
>   and then loading that page from a browser cache. Without persistent
>   cookies, the form submission would fail in this case.
>
> Some browsers (specifically Internet Explorer) can disallow the use of
>   persistent cookies or can have the indexes to the cookie jar corrupted
>   on disk, thereby causing CSRF protection checks to (sometimes
>   intermittently) fail. *Change this setting to **None** to use session-based
>   CSRF cookies, which keep the cookies in-memory instead of on
>   persistent storage.*

That will cause it to be a session cookie instead of a persistent cookie.  Session cookies don't have an expiration date so the browser holds them in memory for the current browser session only and then deletes them when the session is over.

You can find info on how to change the Django setting [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/).

Comment: Excellent! I think that's exactly what I need, I'll fix that and run the security scan again. Would that fix the caching problem too since it has no age?

Comment: I believe it should fix the caching issue as well